# how to set exporting default as disable

Tags: highcharts

I want to hide the default exporting button. But I dont want to set each chart as

```
exporting: {
  enabled:false
}
```

This will be too much work because I have lots of highcharts pages.

Any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the global `Highcharts` options :

```
Highcharts.setOptions ( {
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
} )
```

**This piece of code just have to be included in each page you have a chart, *You don't have to modify every chart* to change this option.**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RwUHY/)

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you. Could you please explain what it does?  And is it possible to selectively enable the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable by disabling context buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/45kqw/

```
exporting:{
            buttons:{
                contextButton:{
                    enabled:false
                }
            }
        },
```